# How to prevent overlap of labels in Plotly parallel category plot?

Tags: python, formatting, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

[image]

The labels on the top are overlapping with each other. From what I have [found](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1703) till now, there is no built in solution for this. I am however trying to find a workaround for the same. I have already tried-

1. Adding `<br>` to the argument (labels in different lines, up or down, would be readable) passed to `label` in `go.parcat.Dimension()`. It prints the letters `'<br>'` as it is. No line break.
2. Adding `\n` to the same argument. It does not print the characters backslash or n, but doesn't print a newline either.
3. Reducing the font size in `labelfont_size` in `fig.update_traces()`, but for the text to not have overlap, the required fontsize is too small to comfortably read.
4. Adding annotations would not work because the category rectangles have to be movable and not static.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df =  {}
dim = []

for idx,var in enumerate(['country','School closing','Workplace closing','Cancel public events',
                      'Restrictions on gatherings','Close public transport','Stay at home requirements',
                      'Restrictions on internal movement','International travel controls',
                      'Public information campaigns']):
    df[var] = np.random.randint(4, size=4)
    dim.append(go.parcats.Dimension(values=df[var], label=var.title(), categoryorder='category ascending'))

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
go.Figure(data = [go.Parcats(dimensions=[x for x in dim],
        line={'color': df.country})])
```

Comment: I've tried multiple permutations of `label="<br>".join(var.title().split(" "))` nothing works.  Similar issue with sankey diagrams https://community.plotly.com/t/line-breaks-for-sankey-labels/26700

Comment: I think I'll just go with acronyms or something and describe them elsewhere. I also can't seem to add the label names in hovertemplate. I'll ask it as a separate question if I am not able to achieve it.